# How to wrap text around UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, text, word-wrap

I've been doing some research on this. I'm trying to wrap some text around an image.

```
|| Some || Lets say
||Image || i want
to place the text
around here.
```

I know this question's already been asked, but I couldn't find any good answers.
Any ideas? (I don't mind the text being in a UIWebView)

Comment: can you describe in detail how you want to "wrap some text around an image", maybe with a mockup screenshot and please link to the the question with similar problems

Answer (score 1):

UIBezierPath * imgRect =
 [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

```
UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"];
[self.textView addSubview:imageView];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using CoreText follow this tutorial:
[Wrapping text around a shape with CoreText](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-text-around-shape-with-coretext-540)

Otherwise, you can write HTML, and call loadHTMLString:baseURL: on a UIWebView.